# Weird result of asynchronous callback in chrome storage?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, asynchronous, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-storage

I am in the process of creating a "flashcard" program, but need to get the table and the way to add selected words to the table working properly before I continue.
the relevant code is below, with the for loop starting at 555 because for whatever reason that is the value at which i started in saving them.
So basically whenever the user right clicks on a selected word and presses the button in the context menu, it should save that word in chrome storage and output it in the table that is populated via the code below. Now the weird part is works and recognizes how many words are in the local storage tubes, but it fills the table with that many number of words, just with the last highlighted word.

For example, if i have highlighted and selected 3 words, only the very last word will show up on the table, but it will populate 3 rows. Is this a result of the asynchronous callback in the storage.sync.get method or just a stupid mistake on my end?

```
for (i = 555; i < x; i++) {
    var key = i.toString();
    key = 'a'.key;
    chrome.storage.sync.get(key, function (data) {


        var row = table.insertRow(table.length);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);

        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        cell1.innerHTML = data.key;
        cell2.innerHTML = "definition";
        cell1.contentEditable = true;
        cell2.contentEditable = true;
    });
}
```

Here is the set portion of the code:

```
var key = x.toString();
key = 'a'.key;
chrome.storage.sync.set({key : sText}, function(){
}
);
x++;
```

Comment: `var key = i.toString(); key = 'a'.key;` doesn't make sense. What is it supposed to do? How the data is saved in `sync.set`?

Comment: it is adding the character constant in front of the numbers, i read somewhere else that it was good practice although i suppose it doesnt necessarily make a difference. the code seems to work fine for saving and accessing the words one by one, so that leads me to believe the problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: `key = 'a'.key` will always be `undefined`. Instead of these two lines simply use the correct expression in-place: `....sync.get('a' + i, .......` I still want to look at your `sync.set`. Also use [Storage Area Explorer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ocfjjjjhkpapocigimmppepjgfdecjkb) to see the actual state of the storage.

Comment: Oh yeah, the same applies to your `sync.set`

Comment: Hey so when I change it to sync.get('a' + i) and the set accordingly i actually get the undefined values in my table(although I can see the values in that extension you linked). before I was at getting the very last value I added as all the table values, rather than just undefined.

Comment: I don't know how `sText` is set. Also make sure you're using `'a' + x` in `sync.set`